# How to properly change a parent's state through a child component's form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, functional-programming, state

I'm trying to update the state of a shared value on a parent component from a child component after a form is submitted:

**Parent**

```
function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("default");

  function handleSubmitted(n) {
    setSearch(n);
    console.log(search);                                //Doesn't update, and value lost after refresh
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Landing onSubmit={handleSubmitted} />        //Child responsible to update state
        </Route>
        <Route path="/add">
          <Add />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/menus">
          <RestaurantList search={search} />            //Receives updated state after a redirect
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Child**

```
export default function Landing(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="center fullpage" id="landing">
        <div className="landing__contents">
          <h1>DineIn</h1>
          <div className="search">
            <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit} >                   //Call function on parent
              <input type="text" placeholder="D Spot Cafe" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to get `<RestaurantList />` to receive the search value typed by the user in `<Landing />` to perform the actual search query functions, but the states are not changing.

Is my structure completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you example was not complete example so I tried to make an example for you **to change a parent's state through a child component's form and that state is used another child component of that parent component**

**Parent Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Child from "./Child";
import Sibling from "../Sibling";

function CParent(props) {

    const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

    function setOpeningValue(status) {
        console.log('From Child to Parent:' + status);
        setStatus(status);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Child setOpeningValue={setOpeningValue}/>
            <Sibling status={status}/>
        </div>
    );
}
export default CParent;
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

// Child to Parent communication
function Child(props) {
    const {setOpeningValue} = props;
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

    function clickHandler() {
        setOpen(!isOpen);
        setOpeningValue(`changes is ${!isOpen}`);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Open</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Child;
```

**Sibling Component**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function Sibling(props) {
    const {status} = props;

    return (
        <div>
            From Child to Parent to Another Child (Sibling) {status}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Sibling;
```

Comment: In this example it looks like you are using two different states between the Parent and the Child, I'm not sure if this applies to me as I am sharing the same state between Child and Sibling.

Comment: From Child Component, When you click on the button then I am calling `setOpeningValue` function of parent component that comes under the `props`. In that function `setOpeningValue`, I am passing `IsOpen` value. In Parent component, I am setting that value using `setStatus(status)` and the I am passing the same value of status into `Sibling Component`

Answer (score 0):

The onSubmit event on `<form>` element will fire only if you put a submit button inside it and then you push it.

If you want to change the state as you type on the text input, then you need to listen to the `onChange` event on the input text element. So, you'll have something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="D Spot Cafe" onChange={props.onChange} value={props.search}>
</form>
```

Note that you'll need to pass the search value to the child component as well.

Comment: Following your method, the search value becomes a SyntheticEvent object rather than a value

Comment: Also, for my other forms in the same application, I do not have a button for submission and the onSubmit fires after just pressing enter on a single text input field. Unsure about behaviour in multiple input fields

Comment: yeah, you should rewrite your `handleSubmitted` function to:
```
function handleSubmitted(event) {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  }
```